# EJB with Hibernate Provider dosen't create Table

Tags: hibernate, ejb, jta

i want that my JavaEE Container create or update tables automatically. I have a EJB Project and as Dbms i use MySQL. My Application Server is Glassfish. I use Hibernate as provider. But tables where not create. If i manually create the tables all works fine (persist,merge,remove).  Here's my persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="AVS-WEB" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/__avs</jta-data-source>

    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/avs" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="*****" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="******" />

        <!--Hibernate properties -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And this is my exception, if no table available.

**com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'avs.kunde' doesn't exist**

Here's my Class Kunde

```
package de.abs.ejb.bean;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="kunde")
public class Kunde implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(
        name="KUNDE_ID_GENERATOR",
        sequenceName="AVS_KUNDE",
        schema="AVS",
        allocationSize=1,
        initialValue=1)
        @GeneratedValue(
        strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
        generator="KUNDE_ID_GENERATOR")
private Long id;

private String email;
private Long kundennummer;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public Long getKundennummer() {
    return kundennummer;
}

public void setKundennummer(Long kundennummer) {
    this.kundennummer = kundennummer;
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try in first thing to do is to modify `update` to `create` in this line in your file `persistence.xml`:

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
```

Than when your tables are created in database, you can change it to update.